# Youtube API waiting for verification

Tags: youtube-api, google-developers-console

The company I work at uses the YouTube Data v3 API to get some insights from the people that authorized their YouTube account. We've been doing it since halfway 2018, but suddenly 2 months ago from one day to the other we had to verify the consent screen once again without any change. This could take 4-6 weeks to verify which is already a problem because during this period users gets a screen that the app is "untrusted". Now we're 8 weeks further and still no sign of verification being completed. There also seems no way of contacting Google with this issue since all "contact" pages are pulled offline or something.

Does anyone else have this problem or can give any tips to speed up this verification process? We also tried contacting some contacts working at Google, but no answer so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having the same issue here. I received an email after awhile of them wanting to audit my stuff, so i filled out all the needed info and its been 2 weeks since then. Still nothing.

Comment: it took +/- 9 weeks but then it was finally verified...